# Pandas' freq attribute in datetimeindex is missing when converting to a parquet file

Tags: python, pandas, parquet

I tried to store the pandas dataframe in a parquet file and read it back. However, the freq attribute is missing in the index. Am I missing some arguments in the call of `to_parquet` or `read_parquet` functions or just `freq` attribute will not preserve in the to_parquet process? Thanks.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':pd.Series(data=[1,2], index=pd.DatetimeIndex(['2023-08-31','2023-09-01'], freq='B'))})
df.to_parquet('df.parquet', index = True)
df_round_trip = pd.read_parquet("df.parquet")
print(df.index, '\n',df_round_trip.index)
```

and I got an output

```
DatetimeIndex(['2023-08-31', '2023-09-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='B') 
DatetimeIndex(['2023-08-31', '2023-09-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: That's an open issue : [`GH41543`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41543).